# QT: How to write to file another info about processes (PID, file path...)?

Tags: qt

i implement Qt program which write started processes to file but there are only names of processes but i need another info  (PID,time processor, file path). This code works for names. What i have to change or add if i want another informations? Thanks

```
    ...
    process.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    process.setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    process.start("wmic.exe /OUTPUT:STDOUT PROCESS get Caption");
    process.start("cmd", QStringList() << "/C" << "echo" << "process" << "get" << "caption" << "|" << "wmic");

    process.waitForStarted(1000);
    process.waitForFinished(1000);
    QByteArray list = process.readAll();
    ...
```

Comment: That's probably more a question about the tool you're calling there (wmic) than Qt itself.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you use some tool to do it. If it not required to use exactly qt,
you can try tasklist command on windows, or top on Linux for example.

Else, try this methods:

```
QProcess::systemEnvironment()
```

Returns the environment of the calling process as a list of key=value pairs. Example:

```
 QStringList environment = QProcess::systemEnvironment();
 // environment = {"PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin",
 //                "USER=greg", "HOME=/home/greg"}
```

This function does not cache the system environment. Therefore, it's possible to obtain an updated version of the environment if low-level C library functions like setenv ot putenv have been called.

However, note that repeated calls to this function will recreate the list of environment variables, which is a non-trivial operation.

```
QProcess::pid()
```

Returns the native process identifier for the running process, if available. If no process is currently running, 0 is returned.

```
QProcess::workingDirectory()
```

If QProcess has been assigned a working directory, this function returns the working directory that the QProcess will enter before the program has started. Otherwise, (i.e., no directory has been assigned,) an empty string is returned, and QProcess will use the application's current working directory instead.